# Extracting information from "Created By" field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there any way I could extract the department or email information from the "Created By" field in a custom list?

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific how you want to extract the information, if it's javascript or c# or via UI.

Here is a simple example, maybe you can do something with it. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Kalender');

    //this query can be done in other ways, I'm getting all items 
    var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    var items = list.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var itemsEnum = items.getEnumerator();
            while (itemsEnum.moveNext()) {
                var item = itemsEnum.get_current();
                var author = item.get_item('Author');

                console.log("Email: " + author.get_email());
                console.log("Name: " + author.get_lookupValue());
                console.log("ID: " + author.get_lookupId());


                }
}, function(sender, args) {
console.log(args.get_message());

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon, apologies for the lack of information. I would like it to be replicated at another column.
What I mean is that, I would also like to show the department of the "Created By" at another column

Comment: At another column where? Another list, same listitem, another site? What do you mean by show department? The SharePoint group the user is member of?

Comment: I would like the "Department" column to be shown at the same list. This "Department" column would be reflecting the department of the person listed down in the "Created By" column.
The thing is I do not want the user to declare his department in the "Department" column, instead it should automatically populate base on his data which I can view if I click his name under the "Created By" column.